# How to handle/deal with people pranking me at work?

Tags: unprofessional-behavior

What can I do about people picking on me at work? When asked they reply with:

> I only pick on people that I like

This keeps happening to me weekly, and has now progressed to pranks that involve messing with my car.

Comment: I think this needs more context; ie what happens, how often, who does it, have you tried to report it.

Comment: Messing with your car? If it involves brake lines, I would question their assertion.

Answer (score 6):

If you have asked this person to stop this behavior, **in a documented way** ( email ) begin doing the following while making sure your supervisor is in the loop.  ( You should usually give your supervisor the chance to address an issue before moving on to HR )

1. Document each occurrence with pictures and dates/times.
2. Make a note of witnesses.
3. After a couple such documented occurrences go to HR with your evidence.

This person sounds like the type of person who needs to be either reprimanded so his behavior changes, or fired.  This is similar to or could be considered  *bullying and should not be tolerate*d.

If the jokes are not well received by the person being pranked and the jokester, then this falls into bullying and typically is not condoned by professional companies.

Answer (score 4):

Pranks at work are one thing, but messing with another person's car is not acceptable.

I would advise that you speak to your manager immediatly. Explain that the atmosphere is making you uncomfortable and that people have interfered with your vehicle. Insist that the behaviour has to stop. As Mister Positive said, keep a paper trail.

If any damage has occured to your vehicle, get it fixed and present the bill to the prankster. Advise your boss that you will be doing this (again, in writing) or, if you are uncomfortable giving the bill to the prankster, give it to your boss.

After you flag this to your boss, if anything further happens to your car call the police, file a report for criminal damage (or whatever your local equivalent is).

This approach may seem harsh or extreme, but cars are expensive. A simple "prank" could cause thousands of pounds/dollars/bolivars of damage, or potentially have an impact on the safety and roadworthiness of the vehicle.

Comment: Im from Venezuela, Just wonder how `bolivars` came 3rd on your thought process when choossing currency. Because our economy doesnt have really good reputation.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Because I'd been looking at your profile after you edited my S.E post and had bolivars on the brain... XD

Comment: That depends on what the OP means by "messing with [their] car". The pranking doesn't necessarily have to involve damaging the car. Could be something as simple as leaving embarassing notes under the wipers.

Answer (score 2):

Tell your boss that this "picking on" is affecting your work and let him deal with it.

Answer (score 2):

If people are messing around in the office then I would document everything, and think about contacting HR.

If they're messing around with your car I would see HR immediately. A few jokes can be pretty bad but interfering with someones car is a criminal offence.

Answer (score 1):

If they are messing with your property, especially if they are making your car potentially unsafe to drive, you need to go to a manager.  Now.

- Document, in writing, what they've done and when.  If you can take pictures, do it.
- Don't discuss the issue with the bullies.
- Don't tell them you're going to speak to a manager.